# How to create sftp user to access to a specific directory only?

Tags: permissions, ssh, sftp

I want to create users for sftp with limited access to specific folders

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/var/www/site1/files/

/var/www/site2/files/

/var/www/site3/files/
```

I want to create sftp user1 to access `/var/www/site1/files/` only to upload website files using filezila
and cannot view any other folders

and likewise for user2 with limited access to `/var/www/site2/files/`

and for user3 with limited access to `/var/www/site3/files/`

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much followed the thing.
The best way is to do this:

1. Mount each of the 3 directories to `/home` directories by appending the following lines in `/etc/fstab`:

   ```
   /var/www/site1/files/ /home/site1/htdocs/ bind 0 0
   /var/www/site2/files/ /home/site2/htdocs/ bind 0 0
   /var/www/site3/files/ /home/site3/htdocs/ bind 0 0
   ```
2. Use `mount -a` to instantly initiate the mounts.
3. Make sure you have added the users site1, site2, site3 to same group (eg. sftpusers or sftponly). You can use these commands to add the users to groups:

   ```
   usermod -aG sftponly site1
   usermod -aG sftponly site2
   usermod -aG sftponly site3
   ```
4. Make the `/home/{site1,site2,site3}` home directories for corresponding users using:

   ```
   usermod -d /home/site1 site1
   usermod -d /home/site2 site2
   usermod -d /home/site3 site3
   ```
5. Append the following in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

   ```
   Match group sftponly
         ChrootDirectory %h
         X11Forwarding no
         AllowTcpForwarding no
   ```
6. Finally restart the ssh service using:

   ```
   service ssh restart
   ```

See [this post on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/trying-to-setup-a-sftp-user-with-limited-access) for details.

Comment: many thanks for your response i make this steps but it not work with me could you explain the steps with commands

Comment: i got this error in filezilla  Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Error: Could not connect to server

Comment: are you sure you added the ssh-public key in /home/site1/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: could you explain the steps from a to z  how to create a sftp user can upload  and to the www folder using filezilla

Comment: i can't solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

After following [krishna chalise's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1019194/527764) you may need to adjust ownership and permissions.

For example, for user site1:

```
chown root:root /home/site1
chmod 755 /home/site1
cd /home/site1
chown site1:sftponly
```