# How to set ftp to access all /var directories but nowhere else

Tags: 16.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

I set up several websites on VPS with Ubuntu server. I use this [guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/running-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-with-apache2-mariadb-and-php-7-1-support/).

So I added 3 sites. they are in these directories I guess: `sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/spiele33.de`

Then I installed FTP and used this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04).

But this ftp user `Sammy`  can no access to my websites directory.
How can I allow this user and also how can I add ftp user which will be allowed in this directory: `/var/www/html/`
And anywhere on `/var/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting up sftp to login into server with file zilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1024194/setting-up-sftp-to-login-into-server-with-file-zilla) - this is one possible way. In addition instead of FTP (that is less secure) you can use SFTP if you have properly setup SSH connection - see [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/987769/566421).

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019027/how-to-create-sftp-user-to-access-to-a-specific-directory-only

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove a line in config file.

Comment out this line:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```